# How to configure Apache WebServer to be accessed by public domain (or static IP) I have?

Tags: apache, networking, dns, webserver, network-protocols

I am trying to setup a web-server at home on PC.

I have an Static IP address (say 1.2.3.4 or Domain XYZ[dot]com), which I have configured on my router.
When I try to access, `XYZ[dot]com` or "1.2.3.4", it opens my routers login page.

On the other hand, Apache Server, installed on the PC, works fine. when I write localhost/index.html or 127.0.0.1/index.html - it opens that page.

**QUESTION**

- How can I link the Public IP address to the Apache Server (or the website hosted on localhost on my PC)?

**EXPECTED SOLUTION**

- If anyone visits "http://XYZ[dot]com", the website hosted on my PC is opened on his/her web browser.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The router's login page is usually accessed via a private IP. The router's admin interface shouldn't be  made available to the Public Internet.

What you need to do is:

- find out what your router's public IP is (you can use http://whatismyipaddress.com/)
- setup port forwarding on your router. You want connections made to the routers public IP to be forwarded to your PC. Ex: Your router's public IP is 21.21.21.21 and your PC's private IP is 192.168.0.100. You need to configure a rule which says that any connection made to to 21.21.21.21:80 needs to be forwarded to 192.168.0.100:80

As for the http://XYZ[dot]com part you need to setup that domain pointing to your public IP with a `com.` DNS registrar and configure an apache virtual host for that domain (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have static IP ADDRESS then you don't need to do anything extra you just have to add apache exception in firewall then tick the checkbox under private and public column and you are done. then anyone can access your website all over the world.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a permission for that port on your firewall and configure the ports on your router. Keep in mind that most internet providers have business and residential plans. In residential plans it is common for them to block access to ports 443 and 80 externally (enabling your router will not change that because the requests will not even arrive on it).

An excellent [step by step](https://askubuntu.com/a/1390575/1163822) for those who use linux and also want to set up a domain name